# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to run this code and I keep getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` Exception error.

```
public class Heisenberg {
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int[] array1 = new int[5];
    int[] array2 = new int[5];

    Ext(-1, 10, array1, array2);
  } 

 public static void Ext(int q, int w, int[] e, int[] r)  {
    if (q >= 0)
      e[q] = w;
      r[q] = w;
  }
}
```

I am a little new to arrays so all help is appreciated.`enter code here`

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is, that without braces, the `if` applies *only* to the following statement:

```
 if (q >= 0)
  e[q] = w;
  r[q] = w;  // <---- here you get ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception
```

add braces like:

```
if (q >= 0){
  e[q] = w;
  r[q] = w;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the opening and closing braces for the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Error is happening in following line:

r[q] = w;

As this out of if block, value of q is `-1` which is causing the error.

Move it into if block:

```
if (q >= 0){
  e[q] = w;
  r[q] = w;
}
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You call method Ext with parameter `q` with value `-1`. Then you accesing the `r[q] = w;` with -1 which is not defined (array of size 5 is defined on index 0-4).

Why you accesing that?

```
if (q >= 0)
  e[q] = w;
  r[q] = w;
```

This means that if-statement is only compared for the `e[q] = w;`
If you want to have all the code covered by if-statement, you need add braces. If no braces are in if-statement, only the first task is connected to that if :

```
if (q >= 0){
  e[q] = w;
  r[q] = w;
}
```